# Why is logback.encoder StructuredArguments not printing the log?

Tags: java, spring, logging, kibana, elastic-stack

Dependency

```
implementation("net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:${version}")
```

Code Sample

```
import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.keyValue;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestClass {

    public void testLogging() {
        CustomObject customObject = new CustomObject(...);
        log.info("==> Log Sample 1 : customObject {}", customObject);

        log.info("==> Log Sample 2 : {}", keyValue("customObject", customObject));
    }

    //calling testLogging method in main method
}
```

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <timestampPattern>MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS</timestampPattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

[Actual Output]

1st log gets printed to the console but second one doesn't.

[Expected Output]

> According to [this article](https://www.innoq.com/en/blog/structured-logging/#structuredarguments),
> "
>
> ```
> import static net.logstash.logback.argument.StructuredArguments.keyValue;
>
> String orderId = "123";
> log.info("Order saved {}", keyValue("orderId", orderId));
> ```
>
> The `orderId` is both added to the message (through the {}-placeholder) and to the JSON output as a separate field. This can be searched and displayed in Kibana

However, using `keyValue()` the log statement is not

- logging to the console (being ignored at all)
- customObject not listed as a separate filter field in kibana UI

Is there any additional configuration required for this in logback.xml or elsewhere to pick these sort of log statements?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have fixed it. Turns out you can't print the object just like that. You have to convert it to a string representation so the following fixed my problem by calling `toString()` method on the object.

```
log.info("==> Log Sample 2 : {}", keyValue("customObject", customObject.toString()));
```

Some articles suggest that if you using a custom encoder like `LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` you have to put in some configuration like the following in the `logback.xml` to enable picking the `StructuredArguments`.

```
<providers>
    <arguments>
        <includeNonStructuredArguments>true</includeNonStructuredArguments>. 
        <nonStructuredArgumentsFieldPrefix>prefix </nonStructuredArgumentsFieldPrefix>
    </arguments>
</providers>
```

However, if you are using any of the following encoders, then fields will be included in the JSON output by default for AccessEvents generated by these and you don't have to do any custom configuration.

- `LogstashEncoder`
- `LogstashAccessEncoder`
- `LogstashAccessLayout`, and
- the logstash access appenders

[Source](https://gitcode.net/mirrors/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/-/tree/master/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/fieldnames#loggingevent_custom_event)